# How to register entities and generate tables using only Hibernate? (using annotations, not XML)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I'm using Hibernate 5.6.15 and `addAnnotatedClass(Class annotatedClass)` to register entities. But when I get a session and try to save an entity, tables are still not created and I get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". I've set `hibernate.ddl-auto=create`. I also tried to just open and close a session and a transaction first but with no result. I'm using Hibernate 5 for compatibility with Java 8.

```
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
    
    import ua.gov.ioc.exchange.config.HibernateConfig;
    import ua.gov.ioc.exchange.obituary.model.TestEntity;
    
    public class HibernateApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        session.save(entity);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            Properties properties = PropertiesReader.get();
            configuration.setProperties(properties);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(app.model.TestEntity.class);
            configuration.buildMappings();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TestEntity")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id = 1L;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

My properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.181:1521:center
hibernate.connection.username=username
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true
```

Comment: Are you using spring/boot? Can you post your property file, also, you getter methods should have @Coloun annotation, table annotation should include the catalog property

Comment: @user2304483 I'm not using spring/boot

Comment: you have this: hibernate.ddl-auto=update it should be hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Answer (score 0):

- Good example is
  https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/blob/main/hibernate-orm/core/Basic/src/main/java/org/hibernate/brmeyer/demo/BasicOrmDemo.java.
- In my case the problem starts solving when instead of
  `hibernate-core` dependency I used `hibernate-entitymanager` which
  has `org.hibernate.boot` package with
  `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. After that, I finally get
  reasonable exceptions to find out that my DB user also didn't have write
  privileges.
- Considering the same properties in hibernate.properties working code looks like:

```
public class HibernateApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        session.save(entity);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
            return new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(app.model.TestEntity.class).buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```